# Touch uploaded file in php

Tags: php

I would like to change the modification time of an uploaded file because it always returns 01 January 1970, so I am doing the following:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        touch($_FILES["file"]);
        header ('Location: http://www.example.com/php/manager');
        // file uploaded but filemtime is 01 Jan 1970
}
```

Comment: Your `date.timezone` is correctly set in php configuration ? `php.ini`

Comment: You should pass the filename to `touch()` function. You're passing an array.

Comment: touch() expects a filename/path. You're passing in an **ARRAY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing the array to `touch()` !! You need to pass `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` - a string.
Actually though, you need to touch `$target_file` since that's the final destination; after moving, $_FILES will no longer be there to touch

I will be the first to admit this is not a solution to WHY your dates are not preserving, and I will follow this thread, but to what you're wanting to accomplish, this is the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what could be causing the same filemtime in every uploaded file??

Comment: I don't know but will follow this. You should probably do a `stat()` on the file before you upload it.  If the data is there, then the move is the problem.  If not, it's probably a system or apache setting.  Which I didn't cover.  Your call if you want to accept this answer, and I hope someone weighs in with the WHY, vs. a workaround

Comment: OK, I get the answer. If I put this "$myDirectory=opendir("../parent/");" it doesn't work, but if I put this "$myDirectory=opendir("."); everything (filemtime, filesize) is correct. Could you tell me why? Because I need to use the other way, accessing to the parent directory but knowing filemtime of its files

Comment: what I'm saying is, and I wasn't exactly clear, you need to do `stat($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])` and see if the stats are even coming over on the file you upload.  I've never checked that. You're now talking about reading a folder which seems a different topic to me, but may be related.  It might help you to use the backtick operator to call linux commands like `echo ``pwd```, then ``cd ..parent``, or echo ``ls -l`` etc. - for permissions try echo `echo ``pwd```